# How to I return back to the main menu, from a function?

Tags: bash

I have a problem coming back to the main menu, from a function. My BASH script looks something like this

```
 function functionA(){

    while [ "$choice" != x ]; do 
       echo "Press a to take action, and press b to exit and go back to the main list" 
       read choice 
       case $choice in 
          a)
             echo "Now lets do some stuff" 
             read 
             ... 
             ..... 
             ;; 
        x) 
           exit
       esac 
    done 
 }


 while [ "$choice" != x ];do 
     echo "Main list" 
     echo "Press a to go to functionA, press b to go to functionB, and press x to exit the program" 
     read choice

    case $choice in  
        a) functionA 
           ;; 
        b) functionB 
           ;;
       c) exit

    esac 
 done
```

So basically, if the user is in `functionA()` and presses `x` to quit, I want him to come back to the main list, and there he will be able to go to `functionA()` again or `functionB()`, or just press `x` again to quit the whole program.

Comment: You could use the [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) statement to simplify things.

Answer (score 3):

When you input `x` in `function()`, you are calling `exit` in `functionA()` which makes whole script exit. Instead just `return`.

Comment: Any specific return value needed? 0 or 1?

Comment: If you want to a return a value, you can. For example, if you want to see `function()` failed or returns some value computed then you can do `return 42;` and check it after the call with `functionA; ret_value=$?;` But in your code, you don't seem to be using it. So just `return;` would do.

Comment: Two additions : `return;` will actually return 0. There is an implicit `return;` at the end of your function block, so reaching it will have the same effect.

Comment: Damn, too late for an edit ; I was wrong about the implicit return value. From the builtins man : "If n is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed in the function body"

Comment: I tried return but it didn't work either. The weird this is that case a) and b) and *) (in functionA) do include an exit command, and they do actually exit the function and return back to the main list, but not in x) . Everytime I press x it just exits the whole program instead. So pressing all the buttons will at the end just exit me back to the main list, but not when I press x button, it just exits the whole program as I mentioned.

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend You *can't* have `exit` in `functionA` if you want it to return to caller. Instead of `x) exit;` use `x) return;` in `functionA`'s case statement.

Comment: I did. I tried `x) return; ;;` and `x) return ;;` and `x) return 0; ;;` . Yet everytime I press x button in my switch case (while I'm in the function), it shuts the whole program down. 
Or might have misunderstood?

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend You probably did that change in the *main* function (caller), not in `functionA`. Because if you did as I said, it will *not* exit the whole program.

Comment: @l3x here is the real code I have. http://pastebin.com/VNYgeauv
Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Tomb_Raider_Legend You have multiple function calls (functionAA, functionAB etc). Do they all use `return` instead of `exit`? You also have `exit` calls in a nested case statements where you probably wanted to use `continue` (to continue the loop).

Comment: They all actually use `exit`, in each case statements in each functions. I tried `return` only in `functionAA`. And by nested, do you mean the `*) ;;` ?

Comment: In a loop, you have many `case` `esac` blocks. So if you press `x` in any one of them, it'll exit the whole program.

Comment: @l3x I did as you said, and changed ALL the `exit` to `return` except the one at the main list at end, and it is to shut down the whole program- Did I do it right? because my program still have the same problem. I pasted all my code instead for a better understanding. http://pastebin.com/ZphLMdP0

Comment: I am not going to read 1800 lines of code, sorry! Please provide a [MCvE] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @l3x I understand, sorry for that. This one might be better, though it has 300 lines, most of the functions look the same, and I also minimized each one as much as possible. http://pastebin.com/PqS39Vis